# Getting Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM error in pom

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I have created spring boot project through spring initializr, While importing new maven project eclipse shows  following error. NOTE: I am using eclipse Luna (32 bit) and java 1.8.

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.3.1.RELEASE from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.3.1.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.3.1.RELEASE.pom. Error code 501, HTTPS Required and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM.
```

Here is my pom.xml file code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.project</groupId>
<artifactId>JodiMilaye</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>JodiMilaye</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>


<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Make sure you have imported the project correctly. If you have created the project from spring initializer then make sure while unzipping and importing you are importing the folder which contains the pom and .project and not a level above that.

Answer (score 2):

try to add the following to your pom and then try again the build
after add this subcode it works for me thanks

```
<repositories>

    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

</repositories>
```

Comment: if even this doesn't work try to build after removing your .m2 directory